# Understanding private instance variable

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a hard time understanding private instance variables through example.  After reading about private instance variables, I went to Xcode and tried to verify how they work.

In the book I'm reading, it states that if you declare an instance variable in the implementation file of a superclass, the instance variable will be private and inaccessible to subclasses.

I tried proving it doing the following without any luck.

```
/** SuperClass interface file**/
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject

-(void) setX;
-(void) printX;

@end

/**SuperClass implementation file **/
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA
{
    int x;
}

-(void) setX
{
    x = 100;
}

-(void) printX
{
    NSLog(@" x is equal to %i", x);
}

@end

/** interface file of subclass **/
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassB : ClassA

@end



/**Main file **/
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool


    { 

        ClassA * a;
        a = [[ClassA alloc] init];

        ClassB * b;
        b = [[ClassB alloc] init];


        [b  setX];
        [b printX];



    }
    return 0;
```

}

The program prints the following:
 x is equal to 100

isn't "x" a private instance variable and inaccessible by object "b", because "x" is declared in the implementation file of superClass "a" while "b" is a subclass?

The books says "instance variables that are to be accessed directly by a subclass must be declared in the interface section and not in the implementation section...Instance variables declared or synthesized in the implementation section are private instance variables and are not directly accessible by subclasses."

Really confused by this.

Comment: I think that `@implementation ClassA {  int x; }` part shouldn't even compile. Is that really how your code is?

Comment: Interesting, it does compile. I've never seen that construction before.

Comment: Ya I just copied it straight from Xcode.  What do you see wrong with that part?

Comment: It's perfectly ok to declare ivars like this. It works like that since Xcode 4.

Comment: @somid, I made a gist with comments for you to explain this - https://gist.github.com/dunenkoff/5963677

Comment: @ThomasW it's valid, although it's still pretty new. the difference is that it is `@private` by default if declared `@implementation MONClass { <HERE> }`, whereas `@protected` is the default in an `@interface` declaration. this is great because you can now hide ivars with physical dependence more easily (build time reduction!).

Answer (score 3):

The methods `setX` and `printX` are public and visible and thus can be called on the instance of `ClassB`. Since they are public they can also be called by the `ClassB`, like this.

```
@implementation ClassB

- (void)fig {
   [self setX];
}

@end
```

What **can't** be done is for `ClassB` to directly access the value x. Like this:

```
@implementation ClassB

- (void)foo {
   NSLog(@"x is now %i", x);
}

@end
```

`ClassB` does not have **direct** access to `x`, but it has *indirect* access to `x` through the superclass methods. This indirect access is an object oriented programming concept known as encapsulation.

Comment: So if you declare an instance variable in the interface file, its public.  If you declare an instance variable in the implementation file, its private.  But whats the difference when it comes to a subclass.  Clearly, in the example I provided, the subclass still had access to a private instance variable.

Comment: You can also make an instance variable private by using `@private` like in @KyrDunenkoff's answer. The subclass does not have direct access to the instance variable, but it has *indirect* access using the methods of the superclass.

Comment: Can object "b" from classB, indirectly change the value of "x" that object "a" see's using methods? 

For instance if this method below was provided in the implementation of superclass ClassA and we wrote [classB setX: 15] in the main file.  Would object "a" read 15 as the new value for "x"? 

    @implementation ClassA

    -(void) setX: (int) xVal
    {
     x = xVal;
    }

Comment: Subclass still can access ivars directly though - if they're declared in `@interface` section and have been made `@public` or `@protected`.

Comment: @somid yes, this indirect modification of the private instance variable is allowed, encouraged even. It is part of encapsulation.

Comment: @thomasW in the example you provided, would class "b" be able to access "x" directly if "x" was declared in the interaction file of the superclass?

Comment: Somid yes, as @KyrDunenkoff mentioned, `ClassB` would be able to access `x` directly if it was in the `@public` or `@protected` sections of the interface file.

Answer (score 0):

Ivars have `@protected` attribute by default, means subclasses can access them. To declare ivar as private, use `@private` attribute before ivar declaration:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
@private
    int x;
}
```

If you declare your ivars in `@implementation` section, the only way for them to be visible to subclasses is to import .m file in your subclass, but your can't use them because they're private.

Or don't use ivars at all, since Objective-C properties now create ivars automatically. If you need a private property, you can declare it via anonymous category in .m file like this:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger x;

@end
```

**UPDATE:**
I think I understand what's confusing you. Public and protected ivars are *inherited* by subclasses and can be accessed directly as instance variables of *subclass*, no need to use accessor methods from a subclass.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kyr.  I'm confused by the text out of the book and how my example relates to it.

The books says "instance variables that are to be accessed directly by a subclass must be declared in the interface section and not in the implementation section...Instance variables declared or synthesized in the implementation section are private instance variables and are not directly accessible by subclasses."

Didn't my subclass just access a private instance variable?

Comment: @somid your subclass didn't directly access the private instance variable. The access was indirect.

Comment: @thomasW I'm still new at this.  What would an example of the subclass  attempting to access the instance variable directly look like?

Comment: @somid check my answer for what is not permitted.

Comment: This is incorrect. Instance variables declared in the class's interface are protected by default, but instance variables declared in class extension interfaces or in implementation are private by default.

Comment: @GregParker, you said exactly the same thing yet you downvoted. Reason?